# Highlight mismatched entries in single dynamic column and present msgbox for entire range

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I am new here and relatively new to VBA, so please bear with me.  I looked around for an answer to this but couldn't find anything, so I apologize if this has already been answered elsewhere and I didn't find it.

I want to search through a specified column of dynamic length and replace the demographics with a system of numbers (the replace code below works fine, but if you have efficiency-related suggestions, by all means go ahead!).  Then what I want to happen is to highlight any entries that do not match the numbers -- these would be strings saying, for example, "Manager" instead of "Boss" or something like that -- and have a message box pop up requesting the user manually code in the highlighted fields.

Currently what is happening is I have Conditional Formatting for any entries that do not match so they get highlighted.  My "For Each Cell" populates a message box for each individual entry it finds, but I just want one message box for the entire range.  Would it be better to highlight the mismatched entries through VBA?  How?  How can I code this to only give one message box for the whole range?

Thank you in advance for any help!

```
Sub ReplaceRaterDemographicCodes()
'Find and replace demographics with their corresponding codes.
Columns("H:H").Select
    With Selection
        .Replace What:="Self", Replacement:="78"
        .Replace What:="Boss", Replacement:="74"
        .Replace What:="Boss 1", Replacement:="74"
        .Replace What:="Peer", Replacement:="75"
        .Replace What:="Direct Report", Replacement:="76"
        .Replace What:="Customer", Replacement:="77"
        .Replace What:="Other", Replacement:="79"
        .Replace What:="Boss 2", Replacement:="72"
        .Replace What:="Boss 3", Replacement:="73"
    End With
    For Each Cell In Range("H2:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
        If Not Cell.Value = 72 And Not Cell.Value = 73 And _
        Not Cell.Value = 74 And Not Cell.Value = 75 And Not Cell.Value = 76 And _
        Not Cell.Value = 77 And Not Cell.Value = 78 And Not Cell.Value = 79 And _
        Not Cell.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox ("There are uncommon demographics listed. Please modify as needed.")
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't really need to loop through everything - just until you know that you want to show the message box, you can just exit the for loop after showing the message box:

```
Sub ReplaceRaterDemographicCodes()
...

For Each Cell In Range("H2:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    If Not Cell.Value = 72 And Not Cell.Value = 73 And _
    Not Cell.Value = 74 And Not Cell.Value = 75 And Not Cell.Value = 76 And _
    Not Cell.Value = 77 And Not Cell.Value = 78 And Not Cell.Value = 79 And _
    Not Cell.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("There are uncommon demographics listed. Please modify as needed.")
        Exit For
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

This way the message box is only shown once and only if it fits your criteria.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Two things: 1) I get a compile error when I try "Dim showbox As Boolean = False" so I tried two lines, one being Dim showbox As Boolean" and then "showbox = False". Is this correct?  2) I am getting an error, "Type mismatch" when I use your code, but it doesn't open the VBA debugger. The concept you are suggesting makes sense, but I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated my answer. I am used to vb.net instead of vba so I am not sure what is causing your error. My updated answer is better anyway since you could stop the for loop once your criteria is met the first time.

Comment: Aha!  I figured out the error.  The `.Select` at the end of the `For Each` was throwing vba for a loop (I still don't know why...).  Just remove that and the code works great!  I added an `Else MsgBox ("All clear!")` to help make sure it's all working and everything looks great.  Thanks for the help =D!

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with @jgridley here is an answer that includes a `MsgBox` for "All clear!".  The `.Select` at the end of the `For Each` line is also removed (as this caused errors).  Cells highlighted in red are done with Conditional Formatting.

```
Sub ReplaceRaterDemographicCodes()

Dim bAllClear As Boolean
bAllClear = True

...

For Each Cell In Range("H2:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If Not Cell.Value = 72 And Not Cell.Value = 73 And _
    Not Cell.Value = 74 And Not Cell.Value = 75 And Not Cell.Value = 76 And _
    Not Cell.Value = 77 And Not Cell.Value = 78 And Not Cell.Value = 79 And _
    Not Cell.Value = "" Then
        bAllClear = False
Exit For
End If
Next Cell

If bAllClear = True Then
    MsgBox ("All clear!")
    Else
    MsgBox ("There are uncommon demographics listed." & vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & "Please modify the cells highlighted in red.")
End If
End Sub
```